# Can't change battery configuration in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, battery

I'm trying to change in my emulator the battery status as capacity and ac status but isn't working.

I made the whole steps:

1) Connected to the emulator via telnet;
2) Tried to use the commands such power ac off and power capacity 70
3) Every time I checked the power display, the same configuration appears and no change I input is save, and the emulator always show the battery with a "!".

FR I saw this link [Change emulator battery level in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252532/change-emulator-battery-level-in-windows), tried it and nothing resolved.

Follow my data about the battery:

power display
AC: online
status: Not charging
health: Dead
present: false
capacity: 0

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like your emulator device has battery option turned off.

#### You can change AVD battery configuration through:

1. *Open AVD configuration file:*

   Default location for Linux/MAC

   ```
   ~/.android/avd/<AVD name>.avd/config.ini
   ```

   Default location for Windows XP

   ```
   C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\avd\<AVD name>.avd\config.ini
   ```

   Default location for Windows Vista and later

   ```
   C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\<AVD name>.avd\config.ini
   ```
2. *Change the line:*

   ```
   hw.battery=no
   ```

   to

   ```
   hw.battery=yes
   ```

Comment: You seems right but this is not a seaming question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You made right. I did it on my computer and sometimes it did not worked too, I just had to set battery status to discharging before setting its capacity.

```
power status discharging
```

Additionally there is a nice tutorial that could help you with additional commands:

http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/07/changing-the-battery-percentage-in-an-avd-android-virtual-device-emulator/

Comment: Thank you Carlos, but it didn't work... I tried the whole configuration, I was pretty sure about the health dead is the issue but nothing resolved.