# How to run, test and handle low battery popup

Tags: java, android, emulation, battery, onpause

I'm currently developing application on Android Studio. My problem is when application is working and shows low battery popup everything get freeze. I have to minimalize and maximalize back application. I guess there is something wrong with onWindowFocusChanged, onPause or onResume methods.

Anyway, I want to know how to simulate on emulator low battery popup. I don't want to wait one hour for my battery get low. What should i do?

Comment: You should be able to do this with emulators. Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568645/cant-change-battery-configuration-in-android-emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the three dots button you have controls to change battery status in the emulator:

[image: Extended controls]