# How do I change android emulator's battery setting?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to change the battery status and level of the AVD (Nexus 5x).

I tried everything in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252532/change-emulator-battery-level-in-windows) question but nothing is working.

Setting battery by AVD manager UI (`... > battery`) works only if I restart the entire emulator but I would want it to change real time so no luck.

Connection to `telnet` succedes but strangely power settings through `telnel` don't get synced to the emulator meaning that everything remains in CLI.

Also, AVD `config.ini` `hw.battery=yes` is already set.

Comment: did you check this?
https://medium.com/@kaushiknsanji/android-battery-mocking-tutorial-988927fa4a35

Comment: That actually worked! But why didn't the emulator work? Everything else in it worked, why not the battery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First enter adb shell:

> adb shell

next set your battery to discharging mode:

> dumpsys battery set ac 0

now set your battery level to 20%

> dumpsys battery set level 20

worked for me when I entered adb shell, and it's not working when I use adb shell dumpsys!

[source](https://medium.com/@kaushiknsanji/android-battery-mocking-tutorial-988927fa4a35)